# Getting local mouse position within window with python

Tags: python

I want to automate a few of the menial tasks that I do every single day both at my rented and home office.

I was looking into how I'd go about getting the local cursor/mouse position within a window rather than the global position on the screen, but as far as I've read online it seems like that's no easy task.

I know that I could use image recognition with PyAutoGui, PyWinAuto, Lackey or the java/python hybrid SikuliX. This of course works, but it seems like small variances in screen sizes and window sizes effectively renders most of the previously taken images unusable and you end up having to re-take most if not all.

The relationship between elements within the window stays the same. (They only scale up/down based on window size)

Is something like this possible? How much work am I looking at here?
I appreciate any nudges in the right direction and I'm open to using other modules if available.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux you can use [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) utility. You can isntall it on most of well-known distributions. E.g on ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

According to [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html#contenttoc4) you can use `xdotool mousemove` command with coordinates relative to specified window.

There is also a python binding for this tool - [python-libxdo](https://github.com/rshk/python-libxdo). To install it in python use:

```
pip install python-libxdo
```

On windows there is [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) scripting utility. And [pyautoit](https://github.com/jacexh/pyautoit) python binding. But I have never tested it so I can't tell if it can help you with your automation tasks.

Comment: Oh, that's brilliant @running.t! Do you know if there are any Windows equivalents?

Comment: @Dixos: Se my eddited answer.

Comment: [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) is also for Windows, and it's not image based, but uses text properties that is more reliable and maintainable. Also AutoIt doesn't support MS UIAutomation technology that is a must for many modern apps.

Comment: To estimate how much work is needed, just read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for pywinauto.